# How do I take the number after a decimal and use just that information in an Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How would I just use the number after a decimal point and use that data in an Excel formula?
IE 5.35 I need to just use the .35 in a formula. Thank you!

Comment: Should `-5.35` return `-.35`?

Comment: and please provide more sample data with possible variations?

Answer (score 1):

With positive numbers you could simply use:

```
=A1-INT(A1)
```

Or:

```
=MOD(A1,1)
```

However, that would return wrong results if you working with negatives. The following would handle that.

```
=A1-TRUNC(A1)
```

Or:

```
=MOD(A1,SIGN(A1))
```

Comment: Well still waiting on feedback on what a negative number should return :)

Comment: @BigBen, very true. Now you ahead of me ;)